Will every material with strong electron-phonon coupling ($\lambda > 1$) have polarons?
Does polaron formation need only strong electron-phonon coupling? Or does it need something else?

That's news to me. I had thought that as long as it is non-zero, there will be polarons. Actually, there will be more, since polarons will couple with light and make polaritons too, but the general idea ought to be that coupling causes new quasiparticles.
